# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required

Tags: php, zend-framework, php-5.2, php-8.2

I upgraded an old PHP application with Zend framework from PHP 5.2 to PHP 8.2 using Rector. Now Its giving me an error as follows,

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'D:\projects\my_project\public/Zend/Application.php'
```

The error is triggerd by the following line in the index.php file,

```
require_once __DIR__.'/Zend/Application.php';
```

This require_once method worked in the earlier version and gave out path as,

```
D:/projects/library/Zend/Application.php
```

The upgraded project gives out the path as,

```
D:\projects\my_project\public/Zend/Application.php
```

making it unable to locate the Application.php file.

I echoed the value of "**DIR**" and its "D:\projects\my_project\public" in both instances.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: `__DIR__` is the location of the file, regardless of the version of PHP.

Comment: @YourCommonSense What exactly I need to do to get the correct path? I tried giving absolute path as "require_once D:/projects/library/Zend/Application.php". This gives the same error in another file where  "require_once __DIR__." is used.

Comment: I assume `D:/projects/library/Zend/Application.php` definitely still exists, then?

Comment: You need to provide the correct path. Which path is correct is only known to you. Looks like you moved your entire project from D:\projects\my_project to D:\projects\my_project\public, but that's just a guess.